# Loops and Cursors in Oracle into Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, function, loops, while-loop

I have a block of code for a function trying to convert it from Oracle to Sql Server:

Oracle Code:

```
    If nDaysAfter = 0 then

    while (IsHoliday(dNextDay) = 1) or (RTrim(To_Char(dNextDay, 'DAY')) in ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY')) Loop
    dNextDay := dNextDay + 1;
  End Loop;

  RETURN dNextDay;

Else   dNextDay := dNextDay + 1;
  For i in 1..nDaysAfter Loop

    while (IsHoliday(dNextDay) = 1) or (RTrim(To_Char(dNextDay, 'DAY')) in ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY')) Loop
      dNextDay := dNextDay + 1;
    End Loop;
    dNextDay := dNextDay + 1;

  End Loop;
  RETURN dNextDay - 1;
  End if;
```

Sql Server code:

```
    If @nDaysAfter = 0 begin

   while (IsHoliday(@dNextDay) = 1) or (RTrim(convert(char,@dNextDay, 'DAY')) in ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY')) Begin
    SET @dNextDay = @dNextDay + 1;
  End;

 RETURN @dNextDay;

End
Else BEGIN 
SET @dNextDay = @dNextDay + 1;
Declare i CURSOR for 1..nDaysAfter Loop

while (IsHoliday(@dNextDay) = 1) or (RTrim(convert(char,@dNextDay, 'DAY')) in ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY')) Begin
      SET @dNextDay = @dNextDay + 1;
    End;
    SET @dNextDay = @dNextDay + 1;

  Fetch i INTO;
  End;
  Close i;
  Deallocate i;
  RETURN @dNextDay - 1;
  End
```

I am having issues converting this line: `Declare i CURSOR for 1..nDaysAfter Loop` it highlight under number 1.     (nDaysAfter is declare as Float)
Thank I will appreciate as much help possible.

Comment: What is this loop doing? This sounds like a job for a calendar table instead of loops.

Comment: Cursors are far better in Oracle than SQL server. I would try to do this in a different fashion so that you don't use cursors. I second the idea of a calendar table instead of all these functions making the same calculations over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd replace the cursor in the SQL server code with a WHILE loop.

```
declare @i int = 1
while @i <= nDaysAfter
begin
    while (dbo.IsHoliday(@dNextDay) = 1) or (RTrim(convert(char,@dNextDay, 'DAY')) in ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY')) 
    Begin
      SET @dNextDay = @dNextDay + 1;
    End
      SET @dNextDay = @dNextDay + 1;

  set @i = @i+1
End

  RETURN @dNextDay - 1;
```

Comment: it worked I changed it a little bit include the @ for I and rewrote this line: `while (dbo.ISHOLIDAY(@dNextDay) = 1) or (RTrim(convert(char,@dNextDay + 'DAY')) in ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY'))`. thank yo uso much for the help